# Print Multiple Columns of Data to Label c#

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

I am creating a GUI that outputs raw serial data onto a textbox, and I want the user to be able to choose certain columns from that data to print onto a label next to the text box every time the data updates. I can do this when there is only one column chosen, however, when I try to add multiple columns, I get the error "Cannot Explicitly Convert string[] to string".  How can I take multiple columns of data, put them into one string, then print the string to the label?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
string[] data_disp = new string[10];
string[] blahArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
int count1 = txt_PRINT_COLUMN_2.Text.Split(',').Length - 1;
string[] countarr = txt_PRINT_COLUMN_2.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' });

for (int i = 0; i <= count1;)
{
    int column_data = Convert.ToInt32(countarr[i]);
    double inst2 = Convert.ToDouble(blahArray[column_data]);
    data_disp[i] = Convert.ToString(inst2);
    i++;
}

lbl_SHOW_COLUMN_2.Text = String.Join(",",data_disp);
```

"line" is the incoming data, txt_PRINT_COLUMN_2 is the textbox where the user enters the desired columns, and lbl_SHOW_COLUMN_2 is the label where the data should print.

EDIT: I used string.join which takes care of the string error, however, the string data_disp is still null.  How do I fill it in with the values?
EDIT2: I added `i++` to the for loop and made the condition `for i <= count1`. This worked for the first iteration, however, when the data updated, I got the error: "Input string was not in the correct format" on the line inst2. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're looking for `String.Join()`

Comment: @cubrr thank you! However, my string is still showing up as "null" why aren't the values filling in?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `for` loop, open up the Locals tab in Visual Studio (if you're using Visual Studio), step through the program and see where it fails.

Comment: Are you missing the `i++` in the `for` loop?

Comment: @A.Franklin That helped, the string is only recording the first value though

Comment: "_Input string was not in the correct format_" - This means that you used `Convert.ToInt32` or `Convert.ToDouble` on something that wasn't a proper number.